# Cells image view width will not change

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swift3

I have an image view in a cell and I've change the multiplier so that the width changes depending on the screen size. But the problem is that the width doesnt change accordingly. The width is a ratio of the cells width and the width remains constant to that of my xib width. So my width never changes and the width only appears fine for one of the screen sizes but not the rest. How can I update my width of my image view. There is an image of my auto layout below. I also called layout if needed for my image view and the image view shrinks and does funky stuff so that doesnt work. Below is a picture of the auto layout for the image views width.

[image: Picture of AutoLayout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "ratio", try use "equal width" then set the multiplier to 0.3 for 30% from screen width or if you prefer 40%, make it 0.4.